# Why can't get current email outside domain?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want get email of user opening file:

This is my code getting email, but this code only can get email of users have domain the same with my domain, other domain will return empty:

```
function onOpen(e) {
 Browser.msgBox("hi " +Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());  
}
```

Why can't get current email outside domain?

Can get email of outside domain?

Comment: You can if you explicitly ask for their permission.

Comment: when call getEmail(), it show display page ask permission.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the email but not inside an onOpen() function and neither in other circumstances that are well explained in the documentation [1]:

> The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for
>   example, the user's email address is not available in any context that
>   allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a
>   simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google
>   Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized
>   by the developer instead of the user). However, these restrictions
>   generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or
>   belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.

A possible workaround in your case, would be to create a menu [2] that when clicked will call the function you want, but previously it'll present the consent screen to allow the permissions needed. Example:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Actions')
  .addItem('Welcome', 'showEmail')
  .addToUi();  
}

function showEmail() {
 Browser.msgBox("hi " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());  
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: Can show 1 dialog and request user click to get email when onOpen?

Comment: You need JS for that, and dialogs only allows HTML.